# Rails 6.0 association query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I'm working with ruby on Rails 6.0.
I have two entities, an event table and a gem module e.g. for people (person). One of the fields in the event table is contact_person, which should point to the gem module people (person). When I try to popultae the tables with seed data, I get:
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Contact person must exist

Below you can find the db definitions. I'm quite new here, any hint what I'm doing wrong ?
Thank you for any assistance.

Regards,
Dani

Migrate file for events table:

```
class CreateApplicationEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
        create_table :events
                t.references :contact_person, null: true, foreign_key: { 
                    to_table: :core_people_and_companies_people }
                t.timestamps
        end
  end
end
```

The model file for events:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact_person,
                  class_name: '::CoreModels::PeopleAndCompanies::Person'
end
```

The gem module:

```
module CoreModels
    module PeopleAndCompanies
      Person.class_eval do
         has_many :events, :class_name => 'Event', :as => :contact_person
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: I suppose you try to create Event records in the seed file, you must create the association Person object first, before from Rails 5 forward `belongs_to` association is required by default.

Comment: Person needs to inherit from ApplicationRecord (or ActiveRecord::Base). Does it do that?

Comment: Hi,When I remove all references to the contact_person field (from migrate & models), there is no issue, all work fine. So, it has to do with the way I define the contact_person field.
Regards,
Dani

Comment: Just added data for all entries in the events seed file for contact_person field, and all works fine. But I want to have also some entries where the contact_person field is empty (no contact_person). Need to have it optional with and without contact_person. So at the moment it expects toe have contact_person with data.
How can I make it be optional ?
Regards,
Dani

Comment: Hi, I have resolved it by adding - optional: true to the modles file of events:
  belongs_to :contact_person, class_name: '::CoreModels::PeopleAndCompanies::Person', optional: true

Thank you all.

Regards,
Dani

Comment: @dani If you have found a solution, please post it as an answer instead of a comment. It could be beneficial to other users of the community as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it by adding - "optional: true" to the modles file of events:

"belongs_to :contact_person, class_name: '::CoreModels::PeopleAndCompanies::Person', 
            optional: true"

Thank you all.
Regards, Dani